# print string in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

```
section .text
org 100h
push selected
call output
mov ah,4Ch
int 21h

output:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 4
push ebx
mov ah,0x9
mov dx,[ebp+8]
int 21h
pop ebx
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
section .data
selected DB "I selected a random number between 0 and 99",0xd,0xa,'$'
```

I must pass parameters by stack.

The expected output is:

```
"I selected a random number between 0 and 99"
```

, but real output is:

```
"
═  Я ЪЁ■↔Ё▐☺▲♦K☺▲♦V☺▲♦▲♦☺☺☺ ☻               #♣╓ p♣¶ ↑ p♣        ♣
                                                 h(☺ш♦ ┤L═!fUfЙхfГь♦fS┤      gЛU
═!f[fЙьf]├   I selected a random number between 0 and 99"
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in a debugger ?

Comment: If this is a ".com" executable for DOS, then you should really remove the "e" on all registers (unless you switched to 32-bit protected or unreal mode, but it is not the case in this code)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
mov dx,[ebp+8]
```

it would be ok, but you pushed `ebx` a few lines above, so `[ebp+8]` isn't the first parameter anymore, but the returning address (which follows the parameter). The output you are seeing is the "ascii translation" of your program. ;)
Try with `[ebp+0ch]`.